# Express returning 404 even though status is set to 200

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have a NodeJS Express API written in TypeScript. All API calls are returned using this method:

```js
private setResponseWithStatusCode<TResult>(
    result: TResult, 
    httpStatusCode: number, 
    response: Response): Response {

    let res = response;
    res = res.status(httpStatusCode);
    if (Buffer.isBuffer(result)) {
      res = res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
      const stream = new PassThrough();
      stream.end(result as Buffer);
      stream.pipe(res);
    } else {
      res = res.json(result);
    }

    console.info(`Returning HTTP ${res.statusCode}.`);

    return res;
  }
```

I have the following "log wrapper" configured, which logs the start and finish of all requests:

```js
const logRequestStart = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.info(`${req.method} ${req.originalUrl} (cookies: ${req.headers['Cookie']})`);

    res.on('finish', () => {
      console.info(`${res.statusCode} ${res.statusMessage}; ${res.get('Content-Length') || 0}b sent.`);
    });

    next();
  };
```

This works fine for code that goes the json route. For code that goes the Buffer route, the `console.info` statement emits `Returning HTTP 200.`, but the call results in a `HTTP 404` response, and the finish line in the log wrapper logs `404 Not Found; 204b sent.`. The buffer content is a couple of megabytes.

So, somewhere after code execution leaves my router but before the finish event is raised, Express changes the response from `HTTP 200` to `HTTP 404`. How can that be, and what can I do about it (I am sure that I have done something wrong)?

The code runs in AWS Lambda. CloudWatch logs contain no error information from express or AWS (unfortunately). The function executes in ~2 seconds, with a configured timeout of 6 seconds, and uses ~200 MB of the allocated 1024 MB of memory, so it's well within the environment boundaries.

Comment: Are you sure your code is going to buffer route, I mean did you debug this?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal Good reflection, but yes I verified this through logging. It is definitely going the buffer route, and only then does the HTTP status code change to 404.

Comment: It's hard to say by looking small piece of code. I would suggest you should apply somebreak points and note down the value till the time you are returning. This would definitely help you.

Comment: Silly question: are you calling the endpoint using the correct verb?

Comment: @Christian let's consider no questions silly :) But yes, otherwise express routing would not have invoked the code at all, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when returning a large Buffer response from an Express API running on AWS Lambda, the response code is being changed from 200 to 404 at some point before the response is sent. This is causing the API call to fail and return a 404 error.

To solve this issue check the Lambda function logs and CloudWatch logs for any error messages or warnings that may indicate the cause of the 404 error.And also increase the Lambda function timeout or memory allocation to provide more resources and time to complete the request.

Comment: CloudWatch logs contains no errors (unfortunately). The function executes in ~2 seconds, with a configured timeout of 6 seconds, and uses ~200 MB of the allocated 1024 MB of memory. So it's well within those boundaries. (I'll update the question to include this information)

Comment: Okay just check the middleware or code that might modify the response status before it reaches your "setResponseWithStatusCode" method. There is a chance to get error at middleware or error-handling code that intercepts the response and modifies the status. So ensure that there are no conflicting middleware or error handlers that modify the response in unexpected ways.